# Rendering invalid credentials message in React on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, http-status-code-401, http-status-code-500

Beginner question about authentication, bear with me:

In my React on Rails app, all the authentication methods work correctly, but if a user enters invalid credentials, the console displays a 500 uncaught in promise error. I want to be able to display an "invalid credentials" method on the screen, but, conceptually, I don't know where to start.

In the Ruby controller, I indicated that the login method should return unauthorized:

```
def login
   @user = User.find_by(username: login_params[:username])
   if @user.authenticate(login_params[:password])
      token = encode({id: @user.id})
      render json: {
        user: @user.attributes.except("password_digest"),
        token: token
      }, status: :ok
   else
      render json: { errors: 'unauthorized' }, status: :unauthorized
   end
end
```

But in the console I see only a 500 error.

Any guidance on where I should start would be much appreciated. I just don't know if this is something I need to change on the frontend or backend. Maybe I need a try-catch somewhere? I'm just kind of lost.

Comment: You should have seen status 401 (unauthorized) but you see 500, I think you don't even reach that point in the code. Check your Rails server console  to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code will work if someone enters a valid username but invalid password, but you'll get a `500` error if someone enters an invalid username.

The reason is that [`#find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) returns `nil` if no matching record exists. So after this line:

```rb
@user = User.find_by(username: login_params[:username])
```

`@user` will be `nil` if no such username exists. But in the following line, you call `@user.authenticate` - and, as `nil` has no such method, you get the crash you're seeing.

The fix is straightforward – we can use Ruby's "safe navigation" operator `&.` to only call `authenticate` if `@user` is not nil:

```rb
if @user&.authenticate(login_params[:password])
```

if `@user` is nil, the authentication method won't be called and the code will jump down to the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you! I didn't see this response until now, but that's exactly the conclusion I came to. I did a sort of nested conditional that caught usernames not in the database, but I like the style of your solution much better. After that I set up a chained method on the front end to get the invalid message. Thank you so much!